# Sending Mail works from Perl but not from Java

Tags: java, perl, email

I have a scenario where I am to send email using our own SMTP server using Java. I have an application deployed on Tomcat 6.

1. The functionality to send email works when we use GMail SMTP.
2. The functionality does not work when I try using our own servers.

I get the following error

```
MailException occured while sending emailMail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 172.16.16.1, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 172.16.16.1, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
```

The problem is that everything works fine using the same credentials and configuration parameters from a Perl Script.

I am on a Debain system.

I doubt there is some kind of access rights issue. I am new to Linux and have very limited knowledge.

Can anybody please help?

The Perl SCRIPT

Pasting the Perl script below for reference

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# System Modules
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mail::Sender;

my $subject = q/Testing Mail Server./;
my $smtp = q/localhost/;
my $from = 'Test <no-reply@xxxx.com>';
my $to   = 'shardul@xxxx.com';
my $msg = q/Hi Testing.../;
my $auth    = q{};
my $authid  = q{};
my $authpwd = q{};

eval {
    sendmail( $smtp, $from, $to, q{}, $subject, $msg, $auth, $authid, $authpwd );
};
if ( $@ ) {
    print STDERR "Confirmation Mail Sending to $to Failed.\n";
    print STDERR 'ERROR: ' . $@;
}

sub sendmail {
    my ( $smtp, $from, $to, $bcc, $subject, $msg, $auth, $authid, $authpwd ) = @_;
    my $sender = new Mail::Sender { smtp => $smtp, from => $from };
    $sender->Body( 0, 0, 'text/html' );
    my $result = $sender->MailMsg(
        {
            replyto   => 'test@xxxxxx.com',
            to        => $to,
            bcc       => $bcc,
            subject   => $subject,
            msg       => $msg,
            auth      => $auth,
            authid    => $from,
            authpwd   => $authpwd,
        }
    );
    if ( $result < 0 ) {
        die "$Mail::Sender::Error\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a `java.net.ConnectException` so the Java VM can't connect to the mail server.  It's not really a mail problem since Java can't see the mail server.

You say:

> everything works fine using the same credentials and configuration parameters from a Perl Script.

Is the Perl script running on the same system as Java?  If not it looks like network connectivity problem between the Java host and Mail server.

If the Perl script is running on the same system double check the script is doing what you think it is, perhaps using something like the `netstat` command.  If the server has multiple network interfaces check the Java VM isn't bound to one that can't contact the mail server.

**Update** - Your Perl script is **not** using your mail server at `172.16.16.1` to send mail.  You can see from this line:

```
my $smtp = q/localhost/;
```

that the script is sending mail via the mail server running on the same host as the script.

It does look like a network problem.  Try running the following command:

```
telnet 172.16.16.1 25
```

If you have network connectivity to the mail server on port 25 you'll see something like:

```
$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
Trying 173.194.67.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP fw5sm12835658wib.0
```

If you don't have network connectivity you'll see something like this:

```
$ telnet 172.16.16.1 25
Trying 172.16.16.1...
telnet: connect to address 172.16.16.1: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

If you do have connectivity then there must be something on the local system preventing the JVM from connecting, possibly an `iptables` rules.  For example, network connectivity might be restricted by user id.  Are you running the Perl script as the same user as Tomcat?

Comment: The Perl Script is on the same machine as Tomcat. As a matter of fact in the same directory as Tomcat.

Comment: The Perl script is very simple actually, I have added it to the question for reference.

Comment: @SB. - As I suggested, the script isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: That's fine...I have tried various IP addresses from Java and Perl...works fine for all in Perl and not in Java. I was trying to figure out if the issue is with one server or all the servers and so different IPs.

Comment: @SB. - I still think it's a network problem. Have added more troubleshooting steps to my answer.

Comment: I am able to connect, I get the following

Trying 172.16.16.1...
Connected to 172.16.16.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 inf1gw1.xxxxx.local ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU

Comment: Right, I'm stumped.  There must be something blocking the JVM from connecting.  Perhaps an `iptables` rule?

Comment: I think now I would need to ask the Linux Admin to get involved, but yes I am executing the Perl script as the same user as Tomcat.

Comment: When you do get this resolved please post the solution as an answer!

Comment: Sure. Most probably by EOD today.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as this would certainly help solve similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly configured your tomcat server to connect to use javamail?

I think you need to setup a Resource in your context.xml, and a resource-ref in your web.xml.

Check out this post for steps:

http://haveacafe.wordpress.com/2008/09/26/113/

Comment: I am assuming that as it works fine with GMail, it should work with any SMTP as ling as the required credentials are provided.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was simple, somehow it never occurred to us that as the Perl script is sending empty AUTH parameters

```
my $auth    = q{};
my $authid  = q{};
my $authpwd = q{};
```

it is possible that the SMTP does not require any Authentication to send emails across.

In the Java Program we were setting the username and password as BLANK and so the Java Program was failing. When we disabled Authentication,by setting mail.smtp.auth to false, it worked fine.

I am not sure how good/bad this practice is to not use Authentication while sending emails from an internal SMTP server.

Thanks for all the help.

Regards,

Shardul.